# undefined method `keys' for "{\"prompt\"=>\"What is your name?\"}":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, functional-testing, fixtures

I have a serialized field that I want to use in functional tests in Rails 4.

Fixtures are saving the hash as a string.

```
Step.rb
serialize :custom, ActiveRecord::Coders::NestedHstore

steps.yml
one:
  name: Simple example.
  custom:
    name:
      prompt: What is your name?
```

In `step.custom`, I want the hash `{name: {prompt: "What is your name?"}`. In testing, instead, I get a string along with the error:

```
undefined method `keys' for "{\"prompt\"=>\"What is your name?\"}":String
```

This is causing my tests to fail of course, because my codebase is expecting a Hash. I tried `<%= hash.to_yaml.inspect %>` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
require "yaml"
new_hash = YAML.parse hash
```

Comment: I  very rarely use fixtures (I use FactoryGirl instead), but in this case I would probably run the code I mentioned above in a step definition to massage the data in a format that you need it in.